# Regex match multibyte numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, multibyte

I need to match multi-byte ０１２３４５６７８９ characters from Japanese using a regular expression.

`[0-9]` does not work in this case. How can I got about making this regex? This is my first foray into matching multi-byte strings.

## UPDATE

Matching a 4 digit string, such as birth year, was successful with both UTF-8 and non UTF-8 using the following `regex`

`^([0-9]{4}||[\uFF10-\uFF19]{4})$`

Comment: ０１２３４５６７８９is unicode?

Comment: If it's unicode, see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex equivalent to `/[0-9]/` for these multi-byte numbers in Javascript is

```
/[\uff10-\uff19]/
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var str = '０１２３４５６７８９';
console.log(
    str.match(new RegExp('[０-９]', 'g')),
    str.match(/[\uff10-\uff19]/g) 
);
//returns ["０", "１", "２", "３", "４", "５", "６", "７", "８", "９"] both ways
```

Make sure to save the `.js` file with the proper encoding (UTF-8) if using the unescaped version.